# Editing Category Pages

Tags: categories, template-tags

I want to allow Search engine Robots to index my category pages, But it seems noindex,follow tags is auto add by my theme functions

I want category pages to allow indexing while keeping noindex,follow for search and 404 pages

Here's is part of them (functions.php)

```
/*Add noindex to low value pages*/
function add_noindex_tags(){
    # Get page number for paginated archives.
    $paged = intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

    # Add noindex tag to all archive, search and 404 pages.
    if( is_archive() || is_search() || is_404() )
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">';

    # Add noindex tag to homepage paginated pages.  
    if(( is_home() || is_front_page() ) && $paged >= 2 )
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">';
}
add_action('wp_head','add_noindex_tags', 4 );
?>
```

Can someone help me edit the code?

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure to set up a child theme - don't edit the current theme unless it's a completely custom one. Otherwise, whenever you update your theme, your changes will be lost.

To do:

- Check what folder your current theme is in. As an example, say you're using Twenty Nineteen - it's in a `twentynineteen` folder.
- Create your own folder inside `/wp-content/themes/`. Perhaps `/wp-content/themes/mychild/`.
- Create a `style.css` file inside that folder. It just needs two short comments:

`/*
Theme Name: My Child Theme
Template: twentynineteen
*/`

Note, you need to change the template (`twentynineteen`) to whatever your actual parent theme's folder is. That's it, you have a child theme. Go ahead and activate it, though it won't actually change anything yet.

- Now create a `functions.php` file inside that same folder. Here, you're creating your own version of the function, and giving it a higher priority than the 4 that's used in your parent theme, so that yours will win out:

```
<?php
/*Add noindex to low value pages*/
function add_noindex_tags(){
    # Get page number for paginated archives.
    $paged = intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

    # Add noindex tag to all archive, search and 404 pages.
    if( is_search() || is_404() )
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">';

    # Add noindex tag to homepage paginated pages.  
    if(( is_home() || is_front_page() ) && $paged >= 2 )
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">';
}
add_action('wp_head','add_noindex_tags', 5 );
?>
```

So, the two differences in your child theme's `functions.php` file are that you have removed `is_archive() ||` from one condition (so the noindex tag will no longer be added to all archives, which includes your categories), and changed the priority on `add_action()` to `5`.